# max no of allowed concurrent connections of google cloud sql from app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am using 2nd Gen Google Cloud Sql and running an app engine instance on flexible environment. The app engine connects to the cloud sql to run sql queries. 
I have set up a connection pool to create min of 10 connections and max of 200.

However, I read this - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/diagnose-issues
which says - "***Each App Engine instance running in a standard environment cannot have more than 12 concurrent connections to a Google Cloud SQL instance***."
It however says nothing about flexible environment of app engine.

I tried updaing the min connections in my connection pool as 20. On the dashboard I could see 20 Active Connections. Seems the 12 concurrent connection limit is for standard environment. However I could not find any document confirming the same.

Can anyone educate me on the limits of concurrent connections from flexible environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no limits specific to App Engine Flexible. You can create as many connections as the Cloud SQL instance will allow.

The number of maximum number of allowed connections is described here:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/faq#sizeqps

Keep in mind that this limit is not an indicator of how many connections your instance can handle for your workload. For example, if you have a heavy workload and you use a n1-standard-1 instance, it's unlikely that you can utilize all 4000 connections.

Comment: 12 concurrent connections is too low. Can you please suggest how to optimise connection? I am using below example https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-cloudsql-native-mysql-hibernate-jpa-demo-java , but mostly getting error as `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0 (Native Method)`

Comment: This comment seems misplaced as the question & answer are about GAE Flex. Are you using GAE Flex or GAE Standard?

Comment: I am using GAE Standard